# Which blood craving bug is this?

Tags: species-identification

While sleeping in a Tajik homestay these guys have been feasting on my blood and left (they didn't bother to hang around in my skin). The bite marks are pretty nasty, this one is 5 days old. Locals say they come out of the ceiling, that it is normal and we shouldn't worry. Are they right? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/slA9L.jpg) 
Bite mark (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx33E.jpg)

Comment: Those are ticks. You should check the internet for tick-bourne diseases in Tajik.

Comment: Hi Arjan! Those do look like ticks, as @KarlKjer said. I'm in America, so I can't say for sure if you should worry, but there are [vector-borne diseases](https://www.acq.osd.mil/eie/afpmb/docs/dveps/tajikistan.pdf) in Tajik, some of which are from ticks.  I strongly recommend having a doctor look at that bite, just in case. If possible, bring a bug or two with you. The doctor can identify it and test it for disease if they feel it's necessary. Hopefully the locals are right and it's just uncomfortable.

Comment: Thanks! We have contacted a doctor and were recommended to wait and contact again when we develop fever. After 6 days we are still allright. We only took pictures and threw them away but we should have collected them in a jar or so...  good idea for next time (but hopefully there will be none).

Comment: Some sort of soft tick, as you've already heard.  Here's a paper on tick-transmitted diseases in the are, for your amusement..  https://www.acq.osd.mil/eie/afpmb/docs/dveps/tajikistan.pdf